# c - Write directly to disk, bypass page cache?

Tags: c, caching, flush, disk

I am trying to determine a way to time a write to disk as accurately as possible.

Calling the write() function writes the file first to the page cache, and then later the system automatically flushes it to disk (if my understanding is correct).

Is there a way to bypass the page cache? Or, would the process involve writing to the page cache, and then flushing the page cache (but how would you then time how long simply flushing the specific data that was written takes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Linux you can open the disk device with the O_DIRECT flag to bypass page cache.

Comment: NB: `O_DIRECT` places a number of alignment restrictions on the write operations you can perform. You'll get `EINVAL` errors on your write operations if the buffer, file handle offset, or count aren't aligned properly.

Comment: @duskwuff is correct.   You can use the posix_memalign call to get an aligned buffer for this purpose.